# Ionic Dynamic List Divider

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have been stumped on this problem for a while now, so I am hoping you can get me in the right direction.

My angular factory returns an object which looks like this

```
[{
    name:"Fall",
    year:"20xx",
    id: some_id_#
}, ....]
```

This is a list of semesters with an object for each semester containing the name, year, and semester id.
I am using ionic for my UI framework, and I would like to set up my HTML output to look like this...

2012
    Fall
    Spring
2013
    Winter
    Spring
2014
    etc
    etc

Where each year is a list divider. My HTML currently looks like this

```
<ion-list show-delete="data.showDelete">
    <!-- I WAN TO CHANGE THIS TO BE A DYNAMIC HEADER ADDED FOR EACH NEAR YEAR-->
    <ion-item class="item-divider">
        Semesters
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item ng-show="semesters.length == 0">
        No semesters yet!
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="item-dark item-icon-right" href="#/app/class-list/{{semester.id}}/{{semester.name}}/{{semester.year}}" ng-repeat="semester in semesters">
        <ion-delete-button class="ion-ios7-trash-outline"
                   ng-click="deleteSemester(semester)">
        </ion-delete-button>
        {{semester.name}} {{semester.year}}
        <i class="icon ion-ios7-arrow-forward"></i>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

I don't like cluttering my view with logic, because that belongs in the controller, but I am not sure how to go about it, aha.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way of doing it, but I built a CodePen that does this:

- Take an original list (this would be your real data)
- Modify the list by creating additional items for unique starting letters
- In the view, we see if our data is a letter, and if so, treat it as a list divider

This is kind of like how one of their pens work (http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/uJkCz). It feels slightly wrong to me, but it seems to work well. Here is the controller portion:

```
.controller('RootCtrl', function($scope) {

  //orig data
  var list = [];
  list.push({name:"Gary"});
  list.push({name:"Gosh"});
  list.push({name:"Ray"});
  list.push({name:"Sam"});
  list.push({name:"Sandy"});

  $scope.list = [];
  var lastChar = '';
  for(var i=0,len=list.length; i<len; i++) {
    var item = list[i];

    if(item.name.charAt(0) != lastChar) {
      $scope.list.push({name:item.name.charAt(0),letter:true});
      lastChar = item.name.charAt(0);
    }
    $scope.list.push(item);

  }
})
```

And then the view checks to see if the data is a person vs a letter. Again, this feels a bit lame, but...

```
<ion-list type="list-inset">
  <ion-item ng-repeat="person in list" ng-class="person.letter? 'item-divider':''">
    {{person.name}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

You can run this here: http://codepen.io/cfjedimaster/pen/HqrBf

Comment: I was kinda figuring this was what I needed to do, but thanks for providing a solution! I will give this a whirl

Answer (score 6):

Another solution, using [UnderscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/), would have you "group" your list by the property you're interested in (here, the year), and then you can iterate over those groups in your template.

## Short Version

in your controller:

```
$scope.groupedPairs = _.chain(list).groupBy('year').pairs().sortBy(0).value();
```

in your template:

```
<ion-list>
    <div ng-repeat="groupedPair in groupedPairs track by groupedPair[0]">
        <ion-item class="item-divider">
            {{groupedPair[0]}}
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item ng-repeat="item in groupedPair[1] track by item.id">
            {{item.name}}
        </ion-item>
    </div>
</ion-list>
```

---

## Long Version

Start by grouping your list by the 'year' property.

```
var list = [{
    name:"Fall",
    year:"2014"
}, {
    name:"Fall",
    year:"2012"
}, {
    name:"Spring",
    year:"2012"
}, {
    name:"Spring",
    year:"2013"
}, {
    name:"Spring",
    year:"2014"
}, {
    name:"Winter",
    year:"2013"
}];
var grouped = _(list).groupBy('year');
```

`grouped` is now:

```
{
    "2014": [{
        name:"Fall",
        year:"2014"
    }, {
        name:"Spring",
        year:"2014"
    }],
    "2012": [{
        name:"Fall",
        year:"2012"
    }, {
        name:"Spring",
        year:"2012"
    }],
    "2013": [{
        name:"Spring",
        year:"2013"
    }, {
        name:"Winter",
        year:"2013"
    }]
}
```

But now you want it sorted by the year, so we need two more operations to do that.

First, transform the `grouped` object into an array of key/value pairs.

```
var pairs = _(grouped).pairs();
```

And `pairs` is now:

```
[
    [
        "2014",
        [{
            name:"Fall",
            year:"2014"
        }, {
            name:"Spring",
            year:"2014"
        }]
    ],
    [
        "2012",
        [{
            name:"Fall",
            year:"2012"
        }, {
            name:"Spring",
            year:"2012"
        }]
    ],
    [
        "2013",
        [{
            name:"Spring",
            year:"2013"
        }, {
            name:"Winter",
            year:"2013"
        }]
    ]
]
```

Now we just need to sort by the "key" in each key/value pair.  In other words, the `[0]` property of each pair (which contains the year it was grouped into, e.g. `"2013"`):

```
var sortedPairs = _(pairs).sortBy(0);
```

And `sortedPairs` is now:

```
[
    [
        "2012",
        [{
            name:"Fall",
            year:"2012"
        }, {
            name:"Spring",
            year:"2012"
        }]
    ],
    [
        "2013",
        [{
            name:"Spring",
            year:"2013"
        }, {
            name:"Winter",
            year:"2013"
        }]
    ],
    [
        "2014",
        [{
            name:"Fall",
            year:"2014"
        }, {
            name:"Spring",
            year:"2014"
        }]
    ]
]
```

... which can be easily iterated over in your template.  Given `$scope.groupedPairs = sortedPairs;`:

```
<ion-list>
    <div ng-repeat="groupedPair in groupedPairs track by groupedPair[0]">
        <ion-item class="item-divider">
            {{groupedPair[0]}}
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item ng-repeat="item in groupedPair[1] track by item.id">
            {{item.name}}
        </ion-item>
    </div>
</ion-list>
```

and the full controller code to convert `var list` to `$scope.groupedPairs`, without all the explanation:

```
$scope.groupedPairs = _.chain(list).groupBy('year').pairs().sortBy(0).value();
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses the ng-repeat alias feature to show a grouped date divider from a date object. The key to this solution is the ng-if on the divider. Note the parentheses around the date:'yyyy' filtered comparison, which only adds the divider to the DOM if the previous result year does not equal the current result year. It displays a grouped divider.

```
<ion-list show-delete="data.showDelete"
          ng-repeat="semester in semesters as results">

    <ion-item class="item-divider"
              ng-if="(results[$index-1].year|date:'yyyy') !== (results[$index].year|date:'yyyy')">
        {{results[$index].year|date:'yyyy'}}
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item ng-show="results.length == 0">
        No semesters yet!
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="item-dark item-icon-right" href="#/app/class-list/{{semester.id}}/{{semester.name}}/{{semester.year}}">
        <ion-delete-button class="ion-ios7-trash-outline"
                   ng-click="deleteSemester(semester)">
        </ion-delete-button>
        {{semester.name}} {{semester.year}}
        <i class="icon ion-ios7-arrow-forward"></i>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: This one definitely does the trick for me! thanks @deinerson1, I like this solution since it does not require editing of the input data set!